# Why did privileges change with the new design?

Tags: discussion

I've just noticed that privileges have slightly changed since the new design has been applied.

*Before the update*, my next tracked privilege was **"3500 reputation - Protect Questions"**.

*Now with the new design*, my next tracked privilege is **"5000 reputation - Approve tag wiki edits"**

Is that something that happens regularly ? I guess it's based on the size of the community of the network, the bigger it gets the harder it becomes to access high privileges.

I was just wondering if that was intended to go live with the new design as nothing was mentioned about that on the new site design topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing new, its a common thing happens for every stack exchange sites when it is graduated from beta, privileges will be different for beta and graduated site.

Check this- [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)